# how to validate MaskedEditExtender control for MM/dd/yyyy format?

Tags: asp.net

I am using maskedEditExtender control for getting date..

Code inside MaskedEditExtender is

`cc1:MaskedEditExtender ID="MaskedEditExtender1" runat="server" TargetControlID="ui_txtRequestDateTime"  ClearMaskOnLostFocus="false" Mask="99/99/9999 99:99"  UserTimeFormat ="TwentyFourHour">`

I need DateTime in `MM/dd/yyyy` hh:mm formate ,If i use calenderExtender control i can use Format="MM/dd/yyyy" ,but here i couldt specify the format `MM/dd/yyyy`, its generally "`99/99/9999 99:99`" format, the 1st two 9's for month, how to tell to user that they have to give month only, if i give value above 12, like 23,24 its showing exception..

Please give some idea..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use RegularExpression validator with your textbox as follows:

```
 <asp:TextBox ID="txtDate" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>

 <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="valRegDate" ValidationGroup="OrderAdd"
                        ControlToValidate="txtDate" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Please provide a valid date."
                        ForeColor="Red" ValidationExpression="^(((0?[1-9]|1[012])/(0?[1-9]|1\d|2[0-8])|(0?[13456789]|1[012])/(29|30)|(0?[13578]|1[02])/31)/(19|[2-9]\d)\d{2}|0?2/29/((19|[2-9]\d)(0[48]|[2468][048]|[13579][26])|(([2468][048]|[3579][26])00)))$"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot.. Its showing error message for In Correct format,once i give the datetime in correct format that Error message has to automatically disappear right.. But its not going.. What to for that??

Comment: @Lakshmitha,yes, the error msg should automattically disappear. I've updated my answer with full code, which is working for me..

Comment: Also check whether you are providing correct date format like 02/13/2011 as date

Comment: I am giving input like 06/10/2011 12:12, I have to give time also in 24 hrs format.. whether this creates the problem??  It look only for the date format??

Comment: @Lakshmitha, yes the time is causing the issue. The regular expression i've given within validation expression only meant for 02/10/2011 format. You should find a regular expression for MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm format and replace mine..