# while using maskededitextender all links in master page will disabled in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a text box in my content page of asp.net webapplication. I masked the text box with maskededitextender with date format dd/MM/yyyy. I use custom validator to validate the text box. While entering wrong date format in text box like MM/dd/yyyy(12/23/2011) it will throw validation message "Incorrect date format". During this time it disables all other links in Master page.

How to overcome this problem. Can anyone help me with this?

Thanks.,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all tell us that how are you validating the `maskededitextender`..

> If your page will not pass validation then you can not post back the
>   page or in other words all links on the page will be disabled/ fail to
>   create post back.

Check this SO thread for validation setttings:
[how to validate MaskedEditExtender control for MM/dd/yyyy format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6303351/how-to-validate-maskededitextender-control-for-mm-dd-yyyy-format)